I am performing Spin polarized optimization of Fe2O3 unit cell but my SCF loop is not converging
Here is my input file. I have tried to optimize by varying different parameters such as ecutwfc from 40 Ry to 90 Ry, degauss value from 0.01 Ry to 0.05 Ry, mixing beta from 0.1 to 0.7, and checked with different smearing like fermi-dirac, gaussian, mv but still unable to get first SCF convergence.
&CONTROL
    calculation   = "vc-relax"
    pseudo_dir    = "quantum_espresso/upf_files"
    prefix        = "Fe2O3"
    outdir        = "../out"
    nstep         = 300,
    etot_conv_thr = 1.0D-4,
    forc_conv_thr = 1.0D-3,
/

&SYSTEM
    degauss                   = 1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   = 900
    ecutwfc                   = 90
    ibrav                     = 0
    nat                       = 30
    nspin                     = 2
    ntyp                      = 2
    occupations               = "smearing"
    smearing                  = "mv"
    starting_magnetization(1) =  2.00000e-01
    starting_magnetization(2) =  0.00000e+00
/

&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-06
    electron_maxstep = 200
    mixing_beta      =  4.00000e-01
    mixing_mode      = "plain"
/

&IONS
    ion_dynamics = "bfgs"
/

&CELL
/

K_POINTS {automatic}
 7  7  3  0 0 0

CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   4.745679122   0.000000000   0.000000000
  -2.372839561   4.109878941  -0.000000000
  -0.000000000  -0.000000000  13.145694655


ATOMIC_SPECIES
Fe     55.84500  Fe.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF


ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)
Fe      0.000000   0.000000   2.028907
Fe      0.000000   0.000000  11.884390
Fe      0.000000   2.947288   0.289976
Fe      0.000000   2.947288   4.347789
Fe      2.552426   1.473644   6.666672
Fe      2.552426   1.473644   2.608859
Fe      0.000000   0.000000   4.927742
Fe      0.000000   0.000000   8.985555
Fe      0.000000   2.947288  11.304438
Fe      0.000000   2.947288   7.246625
Fe      2.552426   1.473644   9.565508
Fe      2.552426   1.473644  13.623321
O      -0.778177   1.347843  10.434973
O      -1.774249   3.073089   3.478324
O       1.774249   3.073089  10.434973
O       0.778177   1.347843   3.478324
O       1.556355   0.000000  10.434973
O       3.548498   0.000000   3.478324
O       1.556355   2.947288   5.797207
O      -1.556355   2.947288  12.753856
O      -0.778177   1.599445   5.797207
O       0.778177   4.295130  12.753856
O      -0.778177   4.295130   5.797207
O       0.778177   1.599445  12.753856
O       1.774249   2.821487   1.159441
O       3.330603   0.125801   8.116090
O       1.774249   0.125801   1.159441
O       3.330603   2.821487   8.116090
O       4.108781   1.473644   1.159441
O       0.996072   1.473644   8.116090


Could you post the output file too? It will help to see why you did not get convergence. Is the accuracy alternating in every iteration, or is it too slow to converge, or maybe it didn't even go through one iteration of first scf cycle (which might mean inadequate computational resource)?

The first thing you need to do is a convergence study of such parameters. Maybe selecting them by hand is the problem.
